# Datatables pagination not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

For some reason the pagination on my datatable isn't working... I get no errors and everything else seems to work fine except pagination...

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Clicking on the buttons does nothing and also returns no errors.

I am simply loading it in jQuery on page ready like so:

```
('#participantsTable').DataTable({
        bSortable: true,
        paging: true,
        bFilter: true,
    });
```

The sorting works, the filter works, just the paging doesn't.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<table id="participantsTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Name</th> 
            <th>Email</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td class="participant-name">Simon</td>
               <td class="participant-email">email@email.com</td>
           </tr>
           //20 more tr's
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: No reason why it shouldn't. I just copy-pasted your code and it works fine. Please edit your post to include a runnable code sample (the `<>` icon). You can include the dataTable .js file from `https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js`.

Comment: I think the block with pagination are coming due to some other css conflict.check which css is applied to your data table pagination.